# LinqToExcel: How do I exclude certain rows?

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-excel

I've been struggling with this for a few days now and I'm stumped.  I'm hoping that someone can provide an alternate suggestion.
Basically, I'm reading data from excel using LinqToExcel.  But I want to exclude all rows with a "Rating" of "NR".  Here's a sample of my data:

```
CompanyName Rating  SalesMan
Apple       2       Steve
Google      NR      Steve
Microsoft   3       John
Dell        1       Steve
Pepsi       3       John
```

I just want to find all companies that belong to Steve but doesn't have a rating of "NR".  My final list should be:

```
CompanyName SalesMan
Apple       Steve
Dell        Steve
```

I've tried the following code but it doesn't work:

1)

```
var masterList = masterDataXL.Worksheet("data_all").Where(d => !d["Rating"].Equals("NR"));
```

2)

```
var masterList = masterDataXL.Worksheet("data_all")
    .Where(m =>
        !m["Rating"].Equals("NR")
        &&
        m["SalesMan"].ToString().Contains(resAnLastName)) // check for last name
    .Select(m => new ResAnTicksDataClass
    {
        Company = m["CompanyName"],
        Rating = m["Rating"],
        Seller = m["SalesMan"]
    }).AsEnumerable();
```

3)  Created a property for Rating and did the following:

```
var masterList = masterDataXL.Worksheet("data_all")
.Where(m =>
    m["Analyst"].ToString().Contains(resAnLastName)) // check for last name
.Select(m => new ResAnTicksDataClass
{
    Company = m["CompanyName"],
    Rating = m["Rating"],
    Seller = m["SalesMan"]
}).AsEnumerable();
var dataList = (from m in masterList
where m.Rating != "NR"
select new ResAnTicksDataClass
{
    ResAnName = m.ResAnName,
    DescrTick = m.DescrTick
}).AsEnumerable();
```

I'm open to any other suggestions that you might have because I'm completely stumped.  Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: What does it do instead of working?  Is there an exception or a compiler error?  If so, what's the message?  Does it give incorrect results?  If so, what are the incorrect results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you select the 'Rating' column in your Excel file and do a search & replace on the selection (CHange 'NR' to '0') and then filter. Should help using a single data type.

As phoog said, converting Excel files into a table, that table will need to specify each column's type. To do so, it'll look only the 10 first rows of your Excel file. So if your file doesn't have a 'NR' value in the first 10 rows, it will set the column type to `INT`, and therefore fail to convert the value 'NR'. 
A simple trick to fix this is to add a row to your Excel file, just before your first data row, with the data using the datatype you want to use.

As an example, if a column is using text values and sometimes the text is using over 255 caracters, make sure the first 10 rows have at least 1 text value using 256 caracters. Else, once it creates the table, the column will be set to `VARCHAR(255)` instead of `VARCHAR(MAX)` and then crash while converting texts longer than 255 caracters.

Conclusion: always make sure the first 10 rows are using the right type and size to fit all the rows of your Excel file!

Comment: I wasn't aware the datatype of the column was based on the 1st 10 rows. Thx @Francis for tip.  I've changed my program accordingly.

Comment: No prob... I've struggled so bad on this in the past, glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

In you first sample you should change this:

```
d => !d["Rating"].Equals("NR")
```

to this:

```
d => d["Rating"] != "NR"
```

It could also be written in a cleaner way:

```
var masterList = 
    from d in masterDataXL.Worksheet("data_all")
    where d["Rating"] != "NR"
    select d;
```

Comment: Thx Wasp. I tried that and I get the error:  Data type mismatch in criteria expression.  I even tried:  d => d["Rating"].ToString() != "NR".  I get the same error.

Comment: That's weird, I tested that code in Linqpad replicating an Excel file with the same layout as yours, and it works fine. I downloaded the binaries of LinqToExcel [here](http://code.google.com/p/linqtoexcel/downloads/detail?name=LinqToExcel_1.6.3.zip), is it the version same you are using?

Comment: Yup.  I'm using the same version.  But i'm still getting an error.  Can I send you the excel file for a real test?

Comment: One more thing, I actually need to work option 2 not 1.  so, i'm using your suggestion on that option.

Comment: Will not be able to have further look in the next few days, I hope you'll solve it anyway :)

Comment: @inquisitive_one if the first occurrence of "NR" is below the 10th row (or maybe the limit is some number other than 10, I don't remember exactly), the driver is probably inferring a numeric data type for the column.  This would explain the data type mismatch error.  I don't remember all the details, but there's probably a way to force it to treat the column as text.  Or, you can hack the system by inserting a dummy row with a dummy text value, and then filtering that row out of all of your queries.